# My init.el gets stuck on trying to install "spinner", a sub-dependency of cider

Tags: package-repositories

I've installed emacs on a new machine (macos) `brew cask install emacs`. My init.el file gets stuck installing cider (clojure ide) because it requires "spinner". When I do: `M-x package-refresh-contents`, I get the message `"Failed to download 'gnu' archive"` which leads me to believe elpa may be down, however, the elpa website itself does not appear to be down. If I try to manually install the package, the specific message is something to do with a "bad request".

I've tried to manually install the spinner.el file just to unblock myself, but that didn't seem to work. So the question is in two parts:

1. How can I dig further into the issue, see if elpa is working, and debug the problem?
2. How can I unblock myself? Does package installation of CIDER not check if "spinner" is already installed?

Comment: Does `M-x eww https://elpa.gnu.org/` work? If not, maybe it's a HTTPS issue. If so, you can switch to HTTP by changing `package-archives` as a workaround, though you're suggested to figure out why HTTPS failed then fix it if you can. You can install  spinner manually with `M-x package-install-from-buffer`, but you are going to need gnu elpa anyway in the future.

Comment: This may be [Bug#36017](https://debbugs.gnu.org/36017), if it is, `(setq gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3")` might work around it without disabling HTTPS completely.

Comment: @xuchuyang `M-x package-install-from-buffer` worked for me working around it. I will report back on the HTTPS when I have time to investigate.

Answer (score 3):

A solution in several lines of code in elisp Emacs init file:

```js
;; Some combination of GNU TLS and Emacs fail to retrieve archive
;; contents over https.
;; https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/cdei4p/failed_to_download_gnu_archive_bad_request/etw48ux
;; https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=34341

(if (and (version< emacs-version "26.3") (>= libgnutls-version 30604))
    (setq gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3"))
```

Taken from here: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/cdei4p/failed_to_download_gnu_archive_bad_request/ettqtlk/

> How can I dig further into the issue, see if elpa is working, and
>   debug the problem?

To find the above solution, some users tried unencrypted HTTP URLs, and it worked:

```js
(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                         ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
                         ("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/")))
```

Comment: `(>= libgnutls-version 30600)` - that should be `(>= libgnutls-version 30603)` I believe.

Comment: @npostavs Probably. Though the fix worked for me as is. The bug(minor incompatibility) is meant to be fixed in Emacs 26.3;

Comment: gnutls only implemented TLS 1.3 in version 3.6.3, and it seems that setting the priority string for earlier versions will break things, e.g., https://github.com/magit/ghub/issues/89

Comment: @npostavs Edited to check for 3.6.4 version, a final TLS 1.3 impl-tion. To be more robust on other distros. My Manjaro(Arch Linux) updated ***gnutls (3.5.19-2 -> 3.6.5-1)*** at *2018-12-31*;(/var/log/pacman.log)